# decision on regular expression length

Tags: regex

I want to accomplish the following requirements using Regex only (no C# code can be used )

•   BTN length is 12 and BTN starts with 0[123456789] then it should remove one digit from left and one digit from right. 
**WORKING CORRECTLY**

•   BTN length is 12 and it’s not the case stated above then it should always return 10 right digits by removing 2 from the start. (e.g. 491234567891 should be changed to 1234567891)
**NOT WORKING CORRECTLY**

•   BTN length is 11 and it should remove one digit from left. **WORKING CORRECTLY**

for length <=10 BTNs , nothing is required to be done , they would remain as it is or Regex may get failed too on them , thats acceptable .

USING SQL this can be achieved like this

```
case when len(BTN) = 12  and BTN like '0[123456789]%' then SUBSTRING(BTN,2,10) else RIGHT(BTN,10) end
```

but how to do this using Regex .

So far I have used and able to get some result correct using this regex 
**[0*|\d\d]*(.{10})**  but by this regex I am not able to correctly remove 1st and last character of a BTN like this **015732888810** to **1573288881** as this regex returns me this **5732888810** which is wrong

code is

```
 string s = "111112573288881,0573288881000,057328888105,005732888810,15732888815,344956345335,004171511326,01777203102,1772576210,015732888810,494956345335";
        string[] arr = s.Split(',');

        foreach (string ss in arr)
        {
           // Match mm = Regex.Match(ss, @"\b(?:00(\d{10})|0(\d{10})\d?|(\d{10}))\b");

           // Match mm = Regex.Match(ss, "0*(.{10})");
          //  ([0*|\\d\\d]*(.{10}))|
            Match mm = Regex.Match(ss, "[0*|\\d\\d]*(.{10})");

          //  Match mm = Regex.Match(ss, "(?(^\\d{12}$)(.^{12}$)|(.^{10}$))");

          //  Match mm = Regex.Match(ss, "(info)[0*|\\d\\d]*(.{10}) (?(1)[0*|\\d\\d]*(.{10})|[0*|\\d\\d]*(.{10}))"); 
            string m = mm.Groups[1].Value;



            Console.WriteLine("Original BTN :"+ ss + "\t\tModified::" + m);
        }
```

Comment: show ur code/command that run the regex...

Comment: code added which I m using . Return all correct except 015732888810 .

Comment: i just simply want to achieve a condition check like above SQL query in Regex . So i can make decision on wat to do if length is 12 or 11 or <=10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
(0(\d{10})0|\d\d(\d{10}))
```

UPDATE:

```
(0(\d{10})0|\d{1,2}(\d{10}))
```

1st alternate will match 12-digits with 0 on left and 0 on right and give you only 10 in between.
2nd alternate will match 11 or 12 digits and give you the right 10.

**EDIT:**

The regex matches the spec, but your code doesn't read the results correctly. Try this:

`Match mm = Regex.Match(ss, "(0(\\d{10})0|\\d{1,2}(\\d{10}))");
string m = mm.Groups[2].Value;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m))
    m = mm.Groups[3].Value;`

Groups are as follows:

index 0: returns full string

index 1: returns everything inside the outer closure

index 2: returns only what matches in the closure inside the first alternate

index 3: returns only what matches in the closure inside the second alternate

NOTE: This does not deal with anything greater than 12 digits or less than 11. Those entries will either fail or return 10 digits from somewhere. If you want results for those use this:

`"(0(\\d{10})0|\\d*(\\d{10}))"`

You'll get rightmost 10 digits for more than 12 digits, 10 digits for 10 digits, nothing for less than 10 digits.

**EDIT:**

This one should cover your additional requirements from the comments:

`"^(?:0|\\d*)(\\d{10})0?$"`

The `(?:)` makes a grouping excluded from the Groups returned.

**EDIT:**

This one might work:

`"^(?:0?|\\d*)(\\d{10})\\d?$"`

Comment: You should also add an explanation along with your answer so that the OP understands what is going on. Thank you.

Comment: hi I tried this too but not working either , can you plz check it by just coping the code i pasted n replace with this regex of yrs . I think with little tweak , this would work . I would be grateful

Comment: You didn't say what to do with 13 digits

Comment: Hi thats work great . but is there a way I can have them in Group[1] as I cant change code in the app where I would be using this and in my app i have read group[1] , so i cant change that for now . so is there a way if the desired result can be in group[1]

Comment: this one 057328888105 isnot changin correctly as this shud be like this 5732888810 (remove first digit if 0[123456789] and take 10 digits next)  also this one 0573288881000 (13 digits) is coming as 5732888810 and not coming as right most 10 digits as shud be this 3288881000

Comment: yes bro , they r retirning the result but in Group[3] :(  how can I get them into Group[1] any idea ? as i cant change the code , need ot do this with no code change

Comment: Hmm, this worked for me: group[1] should be just the ten digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?(^\d{12}$)(?(^0[1-9])0?(?<digit>.{10})|\d*(?<digit>.{10}))|\d*(?<digit>.{10}))
```

which does the exact same thing as sql query + giving result in Group[1] all the time  so i didn't had to change the code a bit :)